# Hiding php file name in JS

Tags: javascript, php

Should anyone tell me if there's a way hide my php file name in JS?

Front-end:

```
var goToUrl= "veryLongNameThatYouCannotGuess.php";
```

calls the back-end file "veryLongNameThatYouCannotGuess.php".

I don't really want to expose it so any user could see it in the console. Call me paranoid but I want to give the least possible information about the backend's structure. Any hint how to hide it would be great, thank you.

Comment: Security through obscurity is a fallacy, not worth wasting time on. Secure your endpoint so when accessing `veryLongNameThatYouCannotGuess.php` it checks whatever it needs to check, then it doesn't matter who accesses it

Comment: What are you using the link for? You may be able to just use PHP code instead of using JavaScript. That way you don't have to worry about anyone seeing the file name... I also agree with @JimL, your file structure will not really do much to "protect you"

Comment: @JimL, there's heavy backend check of course, I just wanted to make sure that even the php file's name is hidden. You think it isn't worth to worry about it?

Comment: It definitely isn't

Comment: You cant hide file names in js, since you can easily see what your browser requests in any modern browser debugger. :)

Comment: @Samuel, unfortunately it is a requirement to use both, otherwise I wouldn't bother.

Comment: @vicbyte, yes, this is why I talked about the console :)

Comment: @JimL, thanks, in this case I just leave it as is.

Comment: @all, thanks for contributing, I close the question then.

Comment: @idontgetit to elaborate on what vicbyte said; every ajax request you can be seen from your Console. So not much use their...

Comment: Well actually you can "hide" your filename and url. But you have to build your entire system around that. You can't just implement it in a existing system out of the blue. Most contest management systems use that method actually. Every request access the same index.php file and gets routed after that. If you send an ajax request your url will always be blank and depending on the parameters you send for example `action: foo` the request is redirected to your file but the user will never be able to get to know the filename.

Comment: @Robin Schambach yeah...sounds like a lot of changes, might do it in a next project though, thanks for the advice

Comment: Alright, since i'm tired of writing the same stuff again and again. There is no way in which you could hide "direct access" to some file just by hiding filename. Rewrite rules doesnt help - they just alias, routing doesnt help - cause it still points to the same code (you can just access the same route directly, and it will point you to exactly the same code). Trying to "protect code" that way is just pointless and completly unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set in htaccess rewrite for specific url like /my-redirect-url and load .php script for this url.

`var goToUrl= "/my-redirect-url";`

`RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^my-redirect-route$   veryLongNameThatYouCannotGuess.php   [L]`

With this code under url /my-redirect-route u can access file veryLongNameThatYouCannotGuess.php

ANSWER EDITED FOR COMMENTS:

If u want to prevent call .php script directly just check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. If it is ur .php filename `exit()`

Comment: This doesnt really help for this use case, since anyone can still access that  file with new link. :)

Comment: hm...okay, I think I just stick to the original recommendations then and leave it as it is. thanks